# IAM issue when doing the one-click integration for twilio and DFCX connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio, dialogflow-cx

I wanted to have an integration with DFCX using the "TWILIO service", but I am having trouble giving permission to "virtualagent-ccai-prod@dialogflow-prod-env.iam.gserviceaccount.com". I am currently using  the one-click integration because of company security. Do you have any other way to make a workaround on the permission or something that is manual integration?

I am getting IAM error when trying the one-click integration.